# How to push (and pop) floating-point registers to the stack on ARMv7 32-bit?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, stack, arm, cpu-registers

How to push (and then pop) a range of floating-point registers to the stack on modern ARMv7 32-bit? Particularily, I am interested in saving and then restoring the scratch (volatile) floating-point registers d0-d7 (or s0-s15, assuming they occupy the same space in the processor).

I saw this approach http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/teaching/2001-02/arm-project/02-sort/apcs.txt with `SFM` and `LFM`, but it seems to be applicable only to very old ARM processors, where registers were named f0-f7 and they were 96-bit each. Both the registers and the instructions seem to have been reworked/renamed after that.

Comment: Get an ARMv7 instruction set reference (because in general you're not going to get very far without one). Start looking under "V". Keep an eye out for the words "load" and "store".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it is difficult to find on the internet, but in the end it seems to be as easy as this (source http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Bcfchhif.html ):

```
VPUSH {d0-d7} ; push d0, d1, ... , d7 to the stack
VPOP {d0-d7} ; pop d0, d1, ... , d7 from the stack
```